# JodaTime parsing date + time + half day is ignoring half day field

Tags: java, jodatime

I can't work out why JodaTime is ignoring the AM/PM after the date e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss a");
    System.out.println(fmt.parseDateTime("23/06/2016 1:00:00 PM").toString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss a"));
    System.out.println(fmt.parseDateTime("23/06/2016 1:00:00 AM").toString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss a"));
}
```

and the output is

```
23/06/16 01:00:00 AM
23/06/16 01:00:00 AM
```

As you can see the input datetimes are 12 hours apart but after parsing and then converting back to a string they are both the same time.

**Edit**: 
Thanks to Sotirios Delimanolis the correct way to do this is to use "hh" and not "HH":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a");
    System.out.println(fmt.parseDateTime("23/06/2016 1:00:00 PM").toString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a"));
    System.out.println(fmt.parseDateTime("23/06/2016 1:00:00 AM").toString("dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss a"));
}
```

and the output is

```
23/06/16 01:00:00 PM
23/06/16 01:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for this, but it seems that the value matching `a` (the halfday of day) is ignored (or overwritten) when using `H` which represents

> hour of day (0~23)

Use `h` for

> clockhour of halfday (1~12)

Comment: you're a champion and I feel like an idiot :) Yes the "HH" should be "hh"